# Chain API http request that depends on response of previous request

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm trying to implement chain http request that will be repeated X times and stop when there is no response from last request.

How it should work.

For example first I call

```
http://example.com/?skip=0
```

and response is:

```
{
   skip=10
},
```

than I call

```
http://example.com/?skip=10
...
http://example.com/?skip=20
```

and on skip 20 response is

```
{
  "message" : "You reach the end"
}
```

I need to stop there. But I have to repeat requests when I'm getting "skip" in response and repeat them on the way that I add skip into next request.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Maxime sure that I tried and I'm trying now...

I'm looking on rx js operators but still not found nothing usefull..

Operators like: takeWhile, timer...

Comment: If you want people to help you on stackoverflow, you should post what you've tried first :) Because people are not here to make things for you, people come here to *help* you. Can you update your answer with what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description it sounds like you actually mean to "paginate" the same query rather than chaining several dependent queries. For that you can use `expand`:

```
// Start with skip 
Observable.of({skip: 0})
  // Feeds the response resulting stream back into this function
  .expand((response) => {
    // Continue expanding if there is a skip parameter
    if (response.skip >= 0)
      return this.http.get(`http://example.com/?skip=${skip}`);
    // Stop expanding if there is no more data
    else
      return Observable.empty();
  }, 1 /* Limit the number of consecutive queries*/);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have too many calls then you could just chain them together as individual methods as below. This will allow you to alter the returned data and act on it at each stage: (i'm paraphrasing the code so apologies if it is not 100% syntactically correct)

```
$scope.call1 = function (values) {
   $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        ...do stuff with data...
        $scope.call2(data);
    })
};

$scope.call2 = function (values) {
   $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        ...do stuff with data...
        $scope.call3(data);
    })
};

$scope.call3 = function (values) {
   $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        ...do stuff with data...
        ...this is the end...
    })
};
```

and kick it all off with a

```
$scope.call1(params);
```

This will call each method in turn only after the previous one has finished.
If you do have lots (i.e. in a kind of for loop) then you would have to add them to a queueing type system.

Comment: so basically 1 function per iteration? thats awful

Comment: I never know how much calls I will have. It depends... sometimes data can be spitted into one chunk and I will need only one call, but in another scenario maybe I will need to make 50 requests.

Comment: The question was how to chain a series of requests, the execution of which depends on the results of the previous execution. That is exactly what the code I provided does. It was only mentioned afterwards that there could be 50 requests. As I said, the process I gave is perfectly valid for a small amount of calls